# 1 Gigabyte Image with GUI and Firefox

Tags: linux, image

I'm looking for a super small image for my Pi < 1 gigabyte. I need it to fit within the memory of the Pi.

I only have 4 requirements: long term availability, a Gui, Firefox, and ethernet drivers.

What can we do?

Comment: why do you want it to fit within the ram of the pi

Comment: I'm trying to PXE boot a bunch of Pi's

Comment: PXE boot is a different problem - what Raspberry PI models do you have?  With the Pi 3 you don't even need any SD cards at all.  Also with PXE boot it doesn't need to fit into memory.

Comment: I'm using the 3, but we might transition to the 3 B+. If the image isn't in the memory or the sd card where is it? We can't have 100+ Pis trying to access a server constantly.

Comment: Why not?  That's how PXE boot works - by storing the root directory on the network.  It would help to have these details in the question.  You either have to manage 100+ OS installs on SD cards or get a server capable of supporting 100+ PXE boot clients.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Tiny Core Linux, see here:
https://www.zdnet.com/article/hands-on-with-picore-7-0-tiny-core-linux-for-the-raspberry-pi/

What have you found so far in your searching?